# Is there any way I can execute these queries with jpa?

Tags: sql-server, jpa, jpql

Is it possible to execute this query in jpa because the only options I see are `.getSingleResult();` or `.getResultList();` which both will throw exception since this query won't return any result.

Is there any way I can execute these queries with jpa?

And the reason I want to do it with jpa is because the `entityManager` already has the connection details and I don't want to create a special connection just for this query.

```
Query LoginkrijoQuery=em.createNativeQuery("USE MDAfondation ;"+
                                           "CREATE LOGIN "+username+" WITH password= '"+password+"',DEFAULT_DATABASE = MDAfondation,DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = english,CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF ;");
LoginkrijoQuery.getSingleResult();
```

well I tried it like this

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.createNativeQuery("USE MDAfondation;\n "+
                         "CREATE LOGIN "+username+" WITH password= '"+password+"',DEFAULT_DATABASE = MDAfondation,DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = english,CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF;\n"+
                         "USE MDAfondation;\n" +
                         "CREATE USER "+username+" FOR LOGIN "+username+";\n"+
                         "USE MDAfondation;\n" +
                         "sp_addrolemember 'stafi', '"+username+"';\n");
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Now it doesn't throw any exception but the query is never executed because when I check in SQL Server the **login , user**  never get created

Comment: What might Query.executeUpdate() do I wonder?

Comment: It throw's an **javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active**    @Alan Hay

Comment: Sounds like you need a transaction then.

Comment: But isn't this a transaction and if not can you tell me how to turn it into a transaction ? @Alan Hay

Comment: does the statement you are executing require a transaction, or is it meant to be non-transactional?  If it is transactional, you should wrap it in a transation, but starting one depends on how you have configured JPA - if it uses JTA, you will have to see how your container is configured to lookup a transaction, otherwise you can use em.getTransaction.begin()/commit() if it is resource_local.  If the statement doesn't require a transaction, you might wrap it in a stored procedure that returns true for success, allowing you to call it using getResultList and avoid the transaction overhead

Comment: I added to the question the part where i tryed with **begin and commit** still dosn't work 

And how do i make a storing procedure return true or false if query succede's when i try with an if statement it say's it's not boolean.
@Chris

Comment: You didn't execute the query using the query.executeUpdate().